# How to Display a Total number of data entered in a Field in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to display a total number of data entered in a field in SQL?

This what I have as SQL statement. I would like to see something like this:

```
                    SELECT u.username, cl.Branch,

                        vt.service,
                        vt.sales,
                        vt.debtors,
                        vt.contact_via
                    FROM Visits_table vt
                    JOIN user u ON u.id = vt.Rep_Id
                    JOIN Client_table cl ON cl.Client_Id = vt.client_fk
                    WHERE vt.Start_Date >= '2015-1-3'
                    AND vt.Start_Date <= '2015-1-10'
                    ORDER BY Start_Date DESC
```

**Output:**

```
Username --- Branch ---- Service ---- Sales ---- Debtors ---- Contact_Via
```

1 username, 1 Branch, Total number of (Services), Total number of(Sales), Total number of(Debtors), Total number of (Contact_Via).
 **All in a single SQL Statement.**

Is it possible to have these total number of data field in 1 single row?

Comment: Specify SUM(column) in the select list, and add GROUP BY u.username, cl.Branch before the ORDER BY.

Comment: @jarlh, SUM? You mean COUNT...

Comment: @MaciejLos. Sorry, obviously I need another cup of coffee. Use COUNT, not SUM.

Comment: @jarlh, I tried to use Count but I didn't get my expected outcome.

Comment: Please I you think you have a good solution for my problem post it out in a SQL statement so I may see how you can help! I much appreciate that.

Comment: In answer to your now deleted question, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769587/front-end-and-back-end-terminology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my comments, do a GROUP BY and use SUM:

```
SELECT u.username, cl.Branch,
       SUM(vt.service),
       SUM(vt.sales),
       SUM(vt.debtors,
       SUM(vt.contact_via)
FROM Visits_table vt
     JOIN user u ON u.id = vt.Rep_Id
     JOIN Client_table cl ON cl.Client_Id = vt.client_fk
WHERE vt.Start_Date >= '2015-1-3'
  AND vt.Start_Date <= '2015-1-10'
GROUP BY u.username, cl.Branch
ORDER BY Start_Date DESC
```

Maybe you should try `COUNT(DISTINCT vt.service)` etc instead.